# How do I make specific shopping cart price rule active at certain time?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I have setup a shopping cart price rule in the magento back-office and I want to make it active automatically at certain time on certain day. is it possible ?

Comment: In Magento Out of the box, one can set the coupon to be active between certain duration of days by setting the From Date and To date in Shopping cart rules however the time setting is not available out of the box.

Comment: You would need to create a module for this that either overwrites the coupon validation logic or uses the controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_couponPost event to add extra logic to the coupon validation that checks the coupon name and then the valid times you want it to apply to. Note the times would have to refer to the server time and not the client time - in case customers are in different time zones.